# ios int to float comparison always evaluates to true

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to compare a CGFloat to an integer value. Based on this value, execute a conditional... pretty standard. However, this will always be true for some reason. I even print out the values and they are clearly less than 800.... I have tried a bunch of different combinations, the most recent is shown below, I thought maybe it was comparing the size of float and the size of the int based purely on its binary values, so I tried this risky little cast operation... Any ideas?

```
CGPoint textViewPoint = [scroller convertPoint:[textView center] toView:(UIView *)self.view];
        NSLog(@"the y coord is %f", textViewPoint.y);

    int size = (int)textViewPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"the yint %d", size);
    //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
    //if  (self.scroller.frame.origin.y >= 0 && textViewPoint.y > 800.0);
    if(size > 800);
    {
        NSLog(@"moving up");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `;` at the end of the `if(size > 800);` line, not the int vs. float comparison. Remove it and all should be OK.

This is because this semicolon is interpreted as the body of your `if` statement, and that's this NO-OP statement that is executed when the condition is true. Then, the rest of your code next to this `if` empty body is outside of the `if` body so is executed whatever the condition value. That's exactly as if you had written:

```
if(size > 800)
{
}
{
    NSLog(@"moving up");
}
```

---

#### *Compiler Warning Tip*

The compiler generally warns you about this mistake. Be sure that you **have the "Empty Loop Bodies" warning activated** in your project Build Settings (compiler flag `-Wempty-body`): this way the next time you do this mistake, you will have a warning about it and will know what is wrong and how to fix it.